# Why is AbortController not defined?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I want to be able to cancel requests with fetch API and use `new AbortController()` Unfortunately I get an error in the console: `AbortController is not defined`

```
//  this.aborter = new XMLHttpRequest()  no error
    this.aborter = new AbortController() error
```

What might be the reason? 
I'm using just vanilla JS without any dependencies.

Comment: On which browser and which version?

Comment: I tried to create AborterController in a browser and same error. Chrome. Why it doesn't support new AbortController() ?

Comment: @karolis2017: Which version of Chrome

Comment: Based on MDN, AbortController is an experimental technology. You should be sure that you are running a browser with the correct version. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController

Comment: updated browser and no problem. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

try

```
this.aborter = new window.AbortController();
```

I found that on Chrome (v77) it didn't recognise AbortController with specifying it as a window property.

Also, after you call

```
this.aborter.abort()
```

you may need to re-initialise

```
this.aborter = new window.AbortController();
```

or future fetch statements won't work (the status will be aborted and it will throw an error!).

Answer (score 5):

The MDN documentation on [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) includes an up-to-date table of supported browsers.

The API is still marked as experimental, although it should be well supported in current browsers. Firefox has it since November 2017 (FF 57), and Chrome followed on April 2018 (Chrome 66).